# Eliminate small polygons in others with same attributes

Tags: polygon, merge, eliminate

I made an itersection of two polygon layers, and I had a lot of small polygons. The tool to eliminate selected polygons, only gives the options to merge with other polygons regarding geometrical characteristics.

I need to eliminate the polygon and merge them with others with the same attribute.

[image]

In this case for example, I need that the small polygons will merge inside the red polygon that has the same attribute.

Comment: So, you want to `dissolve` based on a common attribute/ID?

Comment: Yes, I need to dissolve based on a common attribute, but I need each polygon to stay as an individual. If I use dissolve, all polygons became one entity.

Comment: Either you want to dissolve, or you want your features to stay as they are. Also, did you set an attribute to dissolve by? Please clarify.

Comment: I cannot use the tool "dissolve"  only with the selected polygons I want to merge with the bigger ones. I want to eliminate or merge the polygons in bigger ones, but based on attributes and not geometrical characteristics as the tool "Eliminate selected polygons" provide.

Comment: Based on what exactly do you decide if two (or three) polygons need to be merged? Is this decision always equal if a similar constellation appears, or could you decide not to merge a similar case?

Comment: I need to merge every polygon smaller that a certain surface

Comment: And how do you decide with which other feature you'll merge it?

Comment: They merged based on a common attribute, that is my question.

Comment: So you can use `dissolve`.

Comment: I explain it before. If I use dissolve based on an attribute all polygons will merge, and I only need the small ones to merge with biggers. If I use eliminate selected polygons, I cannot use an attribute as common quality to merge them... That is why i am asking.

Comment: I suggest you add a screenshot of your area after using `dissolve`. Either something went wrong when you used the tool, or you omit some important detail.